# How to Install Ubuntu 12.04 on an HP netbook with Ubuntu-based MI operating system

Tags: 12.04, installation, live-usb, 8.04

I am attempting to install 12.04 on my HP Mini netbook which runs their MI (mobile internet) operating system, based on Ubuntu 8.04.  I've downloaded 12.04, inserted a USB stick, and am looking for the Startup Disk Creator but can find no such program.  What should I do now?

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to install the Startup Disk Creator in 8.04.  Look in Synaptic Package Manager for usb-creator-gtk and usb-creator-common and install them.

Alternatively, you could download and install UNetbootin.  See

http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I tried the second option. When I reboot, I get a UNetbootin screen. It says, "Automatic boot in 10 seconds..." and counts down to 1, but then restarts at 10 seconds over and over again. What should I do?

Comment: Rebooting with your USB?

Comment: Yes. Actually, when I first run the Unetbootin program the dialog box says, "mlabel not found. This is required for Arch Linux install mode." When I click OK, another dialog box says, "7z not found. This is required for either install mode." I clicked OK again and ran the program with the downloaded Ubuntu ISO file.  I should say again that I don't have the pure Ubuntu 8.04 but an HP version of Linux that is modified from Ubuntu 8.04.  It is all GUI.  I have a Package Manager but it doesn't contain the two files you listed above, just some pre-installed games and other apps.

Comment: Have you got a friend that can make the bootable USB?

Comment: I'll try that route.

Comment: Oh, I was assuming you had to make the bootable USB on the computer you are going to convert.  I have another computer that runs Windows. Will that work?

Comment: A Windows PC will not run the Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator but you can try this

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Comment: Success!  I had to put this aside for a while, but I installed 12.04 a couple of days ago and it's worked fine except for a problem with Firefox, which I'll ask as a new question.  Thanks for your assistance, Tony.

Answer (score 0):

Simple console command to create bootable USB:

```
sudo dd if=path_to_ubuntu.iso of=path_to_device
```

It is very important to get the output device name correct, as if you write to the wrong device, you can permanently destroy data on it (even if it's a currently mounted drive).